# FTP Audio File Upload does not work in C#

Tags: c#, ftp, upload

This is the code I'm using that tries to upload an audio file to the FTP server.
It does not work for normal .txt files, neither for .mp3 or .wav files. What am I doing wrong?

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(App.FTP_UserID, App.FTP_Password);
    ftpPath = "ftp://" + App.FTP_IP + App.FtpLIDUploadPath + "/";
    client.UploadFile(ftpPath, "STOR", LocalFilePath + LocalFileName);
}
```

Comment: `What am I doing wrong?` no idea really, you have not told us what goes wrong, i.e the error message

Comment: Though my suspicions are `ftpPath = "ftp://" + App.FTP_IP + App.FtpLIDUploadPath + "/SomeFile.txt";` it needs a file name

Comment: The error just says "An Exception occurred during a WebClient request".

Comment: Do I have to take the file in Bytes and then upload the bytestream, binding it to a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
wc.UploadFile("ftp://ftp-server/directory/filename.ext", Local full path);
```

This should work.